# Calling a shell script from a Groovy/Grails Application

Tags: grails, groovy

How can I call a native shell script from a Groovy / Grails Application?

The shell script resides on the same machine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Put the name (preferably with an absolute path) and the arguments in a list and call `execute()`:

```
['/path/to/script', 'arg1', 'arg2'].execute()
```

The Groovy [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#process-management) suggests to use a simple string instead. I advise against that because it can cause all kinds of problems with special characters, white space in arguments, etc.

Comment: FYI. That link is broken.

Comment: I tried this syntax in groovy script in the On-choice cascade parameter but it ain't worked

['/home/path/to/shell/script', 'arg1'].execute()

Comment: @Triangle: It works for me. I suggest to look at the error message. And your script is executable, right?

Comment: Thanks for the concern Aaron.
It worked for me like this :-
"sh /home/path/to/script.sh arg".execute().

and if the argument is saved in some variable "str" then 

"sh /home/path/to/script.sh ${str}".execute().

 Yes my script is executable.

Comment: @Triangle: If your example works, then `['sh', '/home/path/to/script.sh', str].execute()` must also work. Moreover, it will also work when `str` contains special characters. If the script is really executable, then the first line of the script is wrong somehow. That's what the initial `sh` fixes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Groosh module ([link](https://kenai.com/projects/groovy-groosh/pages/Home))

Comment: Nice - I was exactly searhcing for this!